# How to fix my RE to get my expected arguments of group

Tags: python-3.x

I m new learner to python and learning Regex at this moment.
I made a Regex that is supposed to find all phone numbers.
I think I did it right but my code doesn't seem to be working correctly.

```
phoneRegex = re.compile(r'''(
    (\d{2,3}|\(\d(2,3)\))?           # first 2-3 digits
    (\s|-|\.)?                       # - 
    (\d{3,4})                        # second 3-4 digits
    (\s|-|\.)                        # - 
    (\d{4})                          # last 4 digits.
    (\s*(ext|x|ext.)\s*(\d{3,4}))?   # extension
    )''', re.VERBOSE)
phoneRegex.findall('010 1234 5678 ext1234')
```

I am working on automatetheboringstuff tutorials, and read the Regex chapter through for 3 times.
If there are some minor things that I should read or consider, sorry for my hasty, but I spent roughly 2hrs, and I am happy to any of your suggesting reading materials and help.

I appreciate in advance.

Expected result:

```
[('010 1234 5678 ext1234', '010', ' ', '1234', ' ', '5678', ' ext1234', 'ext',  '1234')]
```

Actual result:

```
[('010 1234 5678 ext1234', '010', '', ' ', '1234', ' ', '5678', ' ext1234', 'ext', '1234')]
```

what is the 3rd thing `('')` and where did it come from?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can break regex in multiple lines and if it will ignore line breaks and spaces, but I know that that `# ...` is inside the string, so they are not comments and probably not what you want

Comment: You have parentheses around the second `2,3` in your pattern. Try replacing `(\d{2,3}|\(\d(2,3)\))?` with `(\d{2,3}|\(\d{2,3}\))?`.

Comment: Thanks Mr.Ezequiel ! It was minor yet critical mistake of mine!!